# I'm getting error in if() statement: NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, if-statement, element

```
company = contact = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='compTitle']")
if browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='partialContents']/div[4]/div[1]/div[10]").is_enabled():
  contact=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='partialContents']/div[4]/div[1]/div[10]")

else:
    contact = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='partialContents']/div[4]/div[1]/div[9]
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='partialContents']/div[4]/div[1]/div[10]"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.72)
```

Comment: You need to use `try/except` to catch the error, not `if/else`.

Comment: This would happen without the `if` as well.

Comment: What do you want to do? Ignore it? Or do you think it shouldn't be happening, and want to understand why it is? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].